# How to build an organisation in pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, religions-and-deities

My char plans to create a **religious organisation**.

**Facts**

1. Name: "Order of the Starfall" (OS)
2. Base of Operation: Sandpoint
3. What dos OS wants to achieve?

   - Live the old ways Aroden suggested
   - Hope and maybe help for Arodens return to come true.
   - Fight infernal cheliax, e.g. expansions plans, support underground in cheliax etc.
4. Campaign OS is nested in: *Return of the Runelords*
5. Initial Acquiration: Leadership feat

**Questions**

1. Are there RAW for creating an organisation?
2. What should I not forget?
3. Do you have some tips or tricks how to ensure growth?

**Remark**

I'm perfectly aware that a lot of sources state that Aroden is dead. Nevertheless AFAIK their is no statement of paizo other than: "We know what happened to him but we won't tell you". Therefore I believe he is still alive or at least hides as another god (see Lathandar -> Amaunator where this happened in FR). However, **this question is not intended to start discussions about Aroden and his where abouts.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adventurer Conqueror King System is also substantially focused on this kind of thing.  You might look there for inspiration or consider switching over. Obviously, something to talk to your GM/Judge about.

Here's the company link. http://www.autarch.co/

Ultimate Campaign is a pathfinder product designed for that purpose.  To boot, the rules are nicely designed to allow players to do their own booking/downtime w/out taking from in-game time. However, two warnings.

1. GET GM APPROVAL to use the book.
2. Communication is key.  Keep a record of all your developments, when they happened in game time and communicate those things to your gm on a regular basis.  Google docs or some other document sharing approach might best facilitate this (the advantage being that you can see the history of changes made to the shared document).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ultimate Campaign has support for building organizations out of "teams". See the Downtime rules on the d20PFSRD - it's harder to follow than reading the book, but the rules parts are all there: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime

Comment: seems to be promising! Even though I already ordered the book :P